# mathematical operation and comparison operation in Solr filter query

Tags: solr

in solr schema.xml ,i got the following entry

```
 <field name="quality" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

During searching, how can i make a filter query with mathematical operation on this field and do a comparison operation.for exmaple as following

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/myindex/select/?q=computer&fq=quality*16>256
```

This mathematical operations will be changing according to the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Solr's [Function Range Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-FunctionRangeQueryParser).

`fq={!frange l=256}product(quality,16)`

Check [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) for a list of all the functions available in Solr.